# Trouble properly dereferencing pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap

Been struggling conceptually with this and I'm not really sure how to get the intended result I'm looking for. I'm building a HashMap class and I'm not sure how to move past the error I keep getting any time I try to access any methods or attributes. I do have a template of a similar HashMap class that uses the vector template instead of a double pointer, but I wasn't able to successfully adapt that to my use here either (plus double pointer is in the template given for the assignment). Here's a simplified snippet of the code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;

template <typename HashedObject>
class HashMap {
    public:
        HashMap() {
            table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                table[i] = NULL;
        }

        enum EntryType {
            ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED
        };

        void test() {
            // This produces a compile error "request for member 'info' in '*((HashMap<int>*)this)->HashMap<int>::table',
            // which is of pointer type 'HashMap<int>::HashEntry*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)"
            cout << table[0].info << endl;
            // But when I use ->, it just crashes at runtime.
            cout << table[0]->info << endl;
        }

    private:
        struct HashEntry 
        {
            HashedObject element;
            EntryType info;

            HashEntry(const HashedObject & e = HashedObject(), EntryType i = EMPTY): element(e), info(i) {}
        };          

        HashEntry **table;    
};

int main(void){
    HashMap<int> hashtable;
    hashtable.test();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that I am most likely failing to properly deference the **table, but I'm having a hard time synthesizing what I've read about pointers and references and applying that to this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `table[0].info` needs to be `table[0]->info` since `table[0]` is a pointer.

Comment: If that's the only problem you have, this post can be closed for "typo" error.

Comment: My issue is it seems to crash when I use table[0]->info.

Comment: Of course it does. `table[0]` is `NULL` at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        cout << table[0].info << endl;
```

needs to be

```
        cout << table[0]->info << endl;
```

since `table[0]` is a pointer.

The program crashes since `table[0]` is NULL at the time it is dereferenced.

Change it to:

```
        if ( table[0] != NULL )
        {
           cout << table[0]->info << endl;
        }
```